Compose time picker AM/PM padding in different language
I am using compose time picker and in German language, AM/PM is a bit squashed and does not have padding around the text.

      TimePicker(
            state = tPState,
            colors = TimePickerDefaults.colors(
                clockDialColor = blue,
                timeSelectorSelectedContainerColor = primary,
                timeSelectorSelectedContentColor = blue,
                timeSelectorUnselectedContainerColor = blue,
                periodSelectorSelectedContainerColor = primary,
                periodSelectorSelectedContentColor = blue,
                periodSelectorUnselectedContainerColor = blue,
                )
        )

Any suggestions on how to resolve this please?
Thanks
R
